# Checkbox input undefined when unchecked - AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

I have an issue with my `AngularJS` checkbox where they become `undefined` when they are unchecked. Can't figure out why this is happening.

```
<input type="checkbox" name="available" ng-model="formData.available" ng-true-value="1" ng-false-value="0" required>
```

With the above code; default on page load is `0`. when Its checked it becomes `1`. When I uncheck it it becomes `undefined`

Any help appreciated.

Comment: there's an issue with the 'required' attribute

Comment: Can you explain more please

Comment: Is this only one option or are there others? Can't have required if the user has the option to check or uncheck with one option.

Comment: Of course, this is how it should be since you have required validation rule.

Comment: Thanks guys removed `required` and working as expected

Comment: either remove the question, or answer it yourself and mark as answered

Answer (score 5):

Thanks to the comments I've realised that the `required` option is not necessary and was the cause of the issue. Thanks guys!

Answer (score 5):

If you need the required attribute set ng-model-options="{ allowInvalid: true }" so undefined becomes false on the model.

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngModelOptions