# ng-required changing checkbox from false to undefined

Tags: angularjs

I've been banging my head for a while on this one.

I have a checkbox typed input using `ng-model`, `ng-required`, and `ng-change`

When I uncheck a checkbox I expect the `ng-model` to be set to **false**, but it is actually being set to **undefined**

Also when the `ng-required` expression toggles; the `ng-model` also bounces between **undefined** and **false** which in turn causes `ng-change` to trigger.

My actual ng-change code executes some code I do not want to run multiple times.

The simple snippet below shows what I'm running into. I threw a text input into the example to see if it did the same thing. It appears to do the same thing when a user enters a string then deletes it...

**This question is not about text inputs**...I'm mostly surprised that a **false** value is not a valid checkbox value when `ng-required` is **true**.

```js
var app = angular.module('example', []);

app.controller('controller',['$scope', function($scope){
  $scope.inputModel = {
    isSelected: undefined,
    textInput: undefined
  };
 
 $scope.onChangeCounter = 0;

 $scope.requiredModel = true;

  $scope.resolveCheckboxInput = function() {
    if (typeof $scope.inputModel.isSelected === "undefined") {
      return "I am undefined"
    }
    return "I am " + $scope.inputModel.isSelected
  };

  $scope.resolveTextInput = function() {
    if (typeof $scope.inputModel.textInput === "undefined") {
      return "I am undefined"
    }
    return "I am " + $scope.inputModel.textInput
  };
  
  $scope.onChangeCallback = function() {
   $scope.onChangeCounter++;
  };
  
  $scope.isRequired = function() {
   return $scope.requiredModel;
  };
}]);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.8/angular.min.js"></script>


<div ng-app="example">
    <ul>
    <li> Set Checkbox Input to TRUE</li>
    <li> Set Checkbox Input to FALSE</li>
    <li> Toggle ng-required</li>
    <li> Checkbox Input is cleary affected</li>
    </ul>
    <div ng-controller="controller">
      <label>
        <input type="checkbox"
          ng-required="isRequired()"
          ng-change="onChangeCallback()"
          ng-model='inputModel.isSelected'  />
      Checkbox Input
      </label>
      <br><br>
      <div>
        <b>Checkbox Input:</b> {{resolveCheckboxInput()}}
      </div>
      <br><br>
      <label>
        <input type="text"
          ng-required="isRequired()"
          ng-model='inputModel.textInput'  />
      Text Input
      </label>
      <br><br>
      <div>
        <b>Text Input:</b> {{resolveTextInput()}}
      </div>
      <br><br>
        <label>
          <input type="checkbox"
              ng-model='requiredModel' />
          ng-required
        </label>
      <br><br>
      <div>
        <b>Checkbox Input ng-change Counter:</b> {{onChangeCounter}}
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Credit goes to this SO question/answer: [Checkbox input undefined when unchecked - AngularJS](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48452975/634872)

You need to add `ng-model-options`.

```
<input type="checkbox"
    ng-required="isRequired()"
    ng-change="onChangeCallback()"
    ng-model='inputModel.isSelected'
    ng-model-options="{ allowInvalid: true }" />
```

*I'd usually mark this as duplicate but the answer in the link wasn't accepted, so it may not be apparent that this works.*

Comment: That was a very simple fix for the amount of time I wasted. Joys of programming I guess... I upvoted the answer in the linked post as well.  Thanks a bunch. Checkbox being false stumped me as being invalid for `ng-required`, but I suppose the proper use case for this with a checkbox would be something like accepting a disclaimer.