# Checkbox input undefined when checked - AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

I have a dynamic UI that needs to sometimes make use of a Checkbox to set boolean values.

My input field is defined as such:

```
<input type="{{item.inputType}}"
       ng-model="dirtyItem[item.Column.Name]"
       ng-readonly="(item.Column.IsReadOnlyModal && !isNewRecord) || (item.Column.IsReadOnlyAdd && isNewRecord)">
```

A couple of things.  If this value coming from my database is "True" for this field, it is properly set, I can toggle it to false and when I save it, the value stored in the `dirtyItem` is properly set to `false`.

However, if an item that is loaded to this UI has a value of `false`, the value is properly set to `false` (unchecked) but if I check it, the bound value in `dirtyItem` is set to `undefined`.

What do I need to do differently to get this to work?

Note, I can provide additional code if it's needed, but by breakpoints and inspection, I have verified that proper true/false data is coming from the server, and also the value within the `dirtyItem` is being updated by checking/unchecking.  False values are legitimately `false`, but true values are undefined.

Also, someone else asked this question.  It is similar to mine, but doesn't seem to apply because I'm having an issue with true values, not false.  This did not help.

[Checkbox input undefined when unchecked - AngularJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35113864/checkbox-input-undefined-when-unchecked-angularjs)